# How to merge columns by duplicate rows in awk/unix/R

Tags: r, awk, merge, duplicates

I have an tab delim input file as shown below:

```
Input:
4444    a   b   c   1  4444 1   4444
9990    a   b   c   1  6666 1   2222
9990    a   b   c   2  6667,6668    1   2223
1700    a   b   c   1   3333    1   8786
1700    a   b   c   1   4444    1   8787
1700    a   b   c   1   5555    1   8788
```

For each unique string in $1,$2,$3,$4 i would need to add $5 and merge $6  and add $7 and merge $8 so that the output looks like below:

```
Output:
4444    a   b   c   1   4444    1   4444
9990    a   b   c   3   6666,6667,6668  2   2222,2223
1700    a   b   c   3   3333,4444,5555  3   8786,8787,8788
```

I presume that thiscould have an existing solution. COuld someone offer a solution in awk/unix/R

Comment: Wow, that is *not* the close-reason I would have expected. Granted, there isn't really a good SO close-reason that matches http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ (I did not DV, but ... it is not unjustified, I think).

Comment: [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) solution: `datamash -g 1,2,3,4 sum 5 collapse 6 sum 7 collapse 8 < input.tsv` (Depends on all groups being adjacent like in your example; if not add `-s` to the options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **R**, *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

# example data
Input <- fread("
4444    a   b   c   1  4444 1   4444
9990    a   b   c   1  6666 1   2222
9990    a   b   c   2  6667,6668    1   2223
1700    a   b   c   1   3333    1   8786
1700    a   b   c   1   4444    1   8787
1700    a   b   c   1   5555    1   8788")

Input[, .(x5 = sum(V5), 
          x6 = toString(V6),
          x7 = sum(V7), 
          x8 = toString(V8)), by = V1:V4]

#      V1 V2 V3 V4 x5               x6 x7               x8
# 1: 4444  a  b  c  1             4444  1             4444
# 2: 9990  a  b  c  3  6666, 6667,6668  2       2222, 2223
# 3: 1700  a  b  c  3 3333, 4444, 5555  3 8786, 8787, 8788
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try the following ***base R*** code, using `merge` + `aggregate`, i.e.,

```
dfout <- merge(aggregate(cbind(V5,V7)~V1+V2+V3+V4,df,sum),
               aggregate(cbind(V6,V8)~V1+V2+V3+V4,df,paste0, collapse = ","))
```

such that

```
> dfout
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V7             V6             V8
1 1700  a  b  c  3  3 3333,4444,5555 8786,8787,8788
2 4444  a  b  c  1  1           4444           4444
3 9990  a  b  c  3  2  6666,666,6668      2222,2223
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(4444L, 9990L, 9990L, 1700L, 1700L, 1700L
), V2 = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"), V3 = c("b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b"), V4 = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), V5 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V6 = c("4444", "6666", "666,6668", "3333", 
"4444", "5555"), V7 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V8 = c(4444L, 
2222L, 2223L, 8786L, 8787L, 8788L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: the solution gave the error: `Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame`

Comment: chas, it seems likely that you named your data something else ... `df`, if not defined as data, is a normal function in R.

Comment: @chas did you used the data in my answer?

Comment: it works now. yes `df` was something else in my case.

Comment: @chas you can change the name of data frame in my code to what you need

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` method to supplement the others:

```r
dat <- read.table(header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
4444    a   b   c   1  4444 1   4444
9990    a   b   c   1  6666 1   2222
9990    a   b   c   2  6667,6668    1   2223
1700    a   b   c   1   3333    1   8786
1700    a   b   c   1   4444    1   8787
1700    a   b   c   1   5555    1   8788")
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise_all(~ paste(sort(unique(.)), collapse = ",")) %>%
  mutate(V5 = sapply(strsplit(V5, ","), function(a) sum(as.integer(a))))
# # A tibble: 3 x 8
#      V1 V2    V3    V4    V5    V6             V7    V8            
#   <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>          <chr> <chr>         
# 1  1700 a     b     c     1     3333,4444,5555 1     8786,8787,8788
# 2  4444 a     b     c     1     4444           1     4444          
# 3  9990 a     b     c     3     6666,6667,6668 1     2222,2223
```